# Android 3.0 error gradle imort error

Tags: java, android, android-studio

> Error:Cannot choose between the following configurations of project
>   :ViewLib:
>     - debugApiElements
>     - debugRuntimeElements
>     - releaseApiElements
>     - releaseRuntimeElements All of them match the consumer attributes:
>     - Configuration 'debugApiElements':
>         - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'debug' but wasn't required.
>         - Found com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' but
>   wasn't required.
>         - Found com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.VariantAttr 'debug' but wasn't required.
>         - Found org.gradle.api.attributes.Usage 'java-api' but wasn't required.
>     - Configuration 'debugRuntimeElements':
>         - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'debug' but wasn't required.
>         - Found com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' but
>   wasn't required.
>         - Found com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.VariantAttr 'debug' but wasn't required.
>         - Found org.gradle.api.attributes.Usage 'java-runtime' but wasn't required.
>     - Configuration 'releaseApiElements':
>         - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'release' but wasn't required.
>         - Found com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' but
>   wasn't required.
>         - Found com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.VariantAttr 'release' but wasn't required.
>         - Found org.gradle.api.attributes.Usage 'java-api' but wasn't required.
>     - Configuration 'releaseRuntimeElements':
>         - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'release' but wasn't required.
>         - Found com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' but
>   wasn't required.
>         - Found com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.VariantAttr 'release' but wasn't required.
>         - Found org.gradle.api.attributes.Usage 'java-runtime' but wasn't required.

Comment: help me please?

Comment: show your gradle file..  module n top level both..

Answer (score 2):

You might have something like `compile project(':ViewLib')` in your `build.gradle`

Try changing it to

`compile project(path: ':ViewLib', configuration: 'default')`

Also, note

`compile` is deprecated [Reference link](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html#new_configurations)

So, instead of `compile` use `implementation`

`implementation project(path: ':ViewLib', configuration: 'default')`

> compile, provided, and apk are currently still available. However,
>   they will be removed in the next major release of the Android plugin.

Comment: i tried it but no response   compile project(path: ':ViewLib', configuration: 'default') ;;;